# angularJs with only one template for all category?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

sorry for my English is not good !
I have followed this example [phoneCat app](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00)
this is one category ( phone list and detail patial templates).
for example , i have many category, all in one category.html file (car, phone,fashion) throught  url  ( localhost/myApp/#/car .. localhost/myApp/#/phone..)

mainLayout

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

js file

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // route for fashion
    .when('/fashion', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/category.html',
      controller: 'fashionCtrl'
     })
    // route for car
    .when('/car', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/category.html',
      controller: 'carCtrl'
    })
.. controller for fashionCtrl and carCtrl
```

partial template html (category.html)

```
template for car
...................
template for fashion
...................
template for phone
```

when i called  the path /#/fashion it display both , but i want only one fashion or car 
_So where is the solutions?
thanks for help !

Comment: I would recommend not combining the templates for different categories into one HTML file. If you have a specific reason for _why_ you think you have to do that, let us know so we can try and suggest a better solution (that doesn't involve one big template).

Comment: thanks for reply, so every time i add new category to the database, i had to add a new template/partial. When delivered to end-user and data changes ? end-user code or i code, then forward

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is to share both controller and template (common scenario)...

So instead of configuring multiple routes, you just need a single route:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // route for fashion
    .when('/:category', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/category.html',
      controller: 'categoryController'
     })
```

In your controller then use $routeParams to get the currently selected category and populate your template with that common data.

```
.controller('categoryController', ['$scope', '$routeProvider', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.category = $routeParams.category;
    $scope.items = fetchFromService($routeParams.category);
}])
```

Sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/dtrZMAcbsbzpWsd9e7Uy?p=preview